# Java SWT javascript function interrupted/delayed?

Tags: java, javascript, swt

I am trying to execute a javascript function in an SWT browser window and I think I am forgetting something that is causing it not to execute before the next line in my java program. This is what I have:

```
browser.execute("showStatus()");
new QuerySite(site); //this takes about 4 seconds to get the web page and process it
browser.execute("hideStatus()");
```

My application does not wait for the javascript function to finish before the next line runs. It does the "Not responding" thing while it is executing QuerySite() (which is normal) but the javascript code does not do what it is supposed to do during this time (show a jqueryui dialog).
The hideStatus() does seem to execute like it should but it is pointless if the showStatus didn't work.

If I have an alert() in the showStatus() function, it will work but I don't want to have something where the user has to click "OK" for every status update. I also tried putting a delay timer before QuerySite() but it didn't change anything. It just made it slower.

Is there a way I can have it wait to run the next line until the javascript is done executing?

Comment: According to the documentation and a brief scan of the `Browser` code, the method should only return once executed. Can you show what `showStatus()` actually does?

Comment: `function showStatus(){
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
    }`

Comment: I guess it must be executing it. It's just that the dialog doesn't show up because the next line in my java code causes the whole application to "wait". Once the java is done, the code to hide the dialog executes so the user never sees the dialog box.